# How can I improve dimensional accuracy of a delta printer?

Tags: marlin, calibration, delta, flsun-qq

I have a `delta` printer that I am trying to fine tune. I have printed a 20mm calibration cube and I get the following measurements:

- X: 20.5
- Y: 20.3
- Z: 20.0

How can I calibrate my printer to improve the accuracy of x and y ?

Comment: Can you first determine the source of the inaccuracy? It could be inconsistency between layers (having them slightly off from one another) or consistent positioning error causing expansion, or just overextrusion.

Comment: I recently calibrated e-steps on the extruder, so I wouldn't think it is due to over extrusion.